# Android Studio code sample build error: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 1.5.1 and tested out the default "Hello World" app, which built perfectly and worked on my phone.  However, I tried to do the same with the [CardEmulation](http://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html) code sample, but received the following error with regards to the template-styles.xml file:

"Error:Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes."

I've tried all of the above suggested fixes but it still does not build the application.  How do I go about resolving this?

Below is the template-styles.xml file that was in the code sample (file path from app folder is /CardEmulation/Application/src/main/res/values/template-styles.xml)

```
<resources>

<!-- Activity themes -->

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

<style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sample" />
<!-- Widget styling -->
<style name="Widget" />

<style name="Widget.SampleMessage">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.SampleMessageTile">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tile</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#7F000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-3.5</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: in the Android Studio terminal, go to the directory where the project is located and enter the command:
    `gradlew build`

For some reason it doesn't initially build right if you use the GUI but after building through the command line, building through the GUI should work as well.